# Angular app unable to consume cross domain API

Tags: angular, ssl, asp.net-core-3.1, angular11

I am working on an angular project and using asp.net core(3.1) to consume APIs. Its working fine on local, but after hosting on local IIS Angular app unable to consume APIs and showing below error in browser console:
[image]

I have hosted both projects(Angular and asp.net core) on IIS where Angular is hosted on localhost where as Asp.net core is hosted as a custom domain website. **Both urls are hosted with SSL**.

I need to **send cookie** in response so I am using **AllowCredentials** in both client and server projects.

I also tried [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/install-ssl-certificate-in-localhost-website-iis) link to create **self-signed SSL certificate** and bind this certificate to both urls. Here also Angular app unable to consume APIs and showing a different error in browser console:
[image]

I noticed that when I open custom domain url(**https://www.aspcore.com/**) in browser it is shown as **not protected** whether used with self-signed SSL certificate or with IIS Express Development Certificate .

**Below is the code used in Angular project:**

```
request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.jwtToken}`,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': GlobalConstants.BASE_API_URL, // Website you wish to allow to connect
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':
            'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE', // Request methods you wish to allow
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type', // Request headers you wish to allow
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent to the API
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      });
```

**Below is the code used in API project:**

```
   services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost/AngularLockdown") //Angular project Url
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()                   
                .AllowCredentials(); //this is required for cookies to be set on the client - set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to true
        }));
```

Please suggest how to fix it, TIA.

Comment: Localhost is a hook-url, so you have to allow any origin, if you want to accept localhost of the client to the api on the server.

Comment: can I use allow any origin along with allow credentials?

Comment: I tried this but now I am unable to send cookie in response.    
                SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

Comment: Try to remove angularLockdown from the WithOrigins-String. Means write .WithOrigins("https://localhost")

Answer (score -1):

I think when u have `https` in your domain (SSL). It will not allow you to call to cross domain.

In order to do this, there are a few solutions. But I suggest some solution and u go google more detail yourself because it is too long to write down how to solve this.

1. Using nginx revered proxy https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
2. Using Angular proxy https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server
3. Using Proxy in Docker https://docs.docker.com/compose/

If you are using private VM or Server, you can go and setup yourself

So, the purpose here is to make the request into one origin to avoid CORS happening.